# Jquery slideToggle( )

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have garage gate image. i want when click on button image should move up.
but problem is that when i click on button image don't move but slide hide from bottom of the image. here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".open").click(function(){
    $(".gate").slideToggle(3000)
  });
});
</script>

<body>

<div class="main">
<a class="open" >Home page</a>
<div class="gate"></div>
</main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), what it does is to hide/show the element by animating the height value.

I've prepared and example using [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the gate opening up when you press the "homepage" word:

See this [working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/bLvWe/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <a class="open">Home page</a>
        <div class="gate"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".open").click(function(){
      $(".gate").animate({
          "top" : "-=" + $(".gate").outerHeight(true)
      }, 3000);
  });
});
```

The position where the animation ends, depends of your final goal, and your applied CSS as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move image, you should use .animate() instead of .slideToggle().
.slideToggle() function show or hide you element.

Answer (score 0):

Slide is not the right answer. Slide is a hide/fade effect not an animation effect. To get the effect you are looking for you need to be animating a css property of the element in question. If you are looking for the element to move down slightly you will need to animate a property that will move the element down. Something like:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".open").click(function(){
              $(".gate").animate({
                    marginTop : '-=30px'
              });
        });
  });
```

you may also want to consider absolute positioning and using the top property. Or css3 translation.